# What are process-specific variables?

Tags: multithreading, smalltalk, pharo

I was trying to load a package apparently written for an earlier version of Pharo (Ratpack, from http://ss3.gemstone.com/ss/RatPack.html into Pharo 1.4).

There I got deprecation warnings about `environmentAt:put:` not being supported for `Project`.

The way to go, according to the documentation, is to use **`ProcessSpecificVariable`**.

My questions are:

- What are they?
- How do I use them?
- How to port "older" (deprecated) code to this new system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find discussion of PSS in [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/pharo/issues/detail?id=4981)

Here is the snippet by Igor on how to use ProcessSpecificVariables :

Suppose MyProcessSpecificVar is a subclass of ProcessSpecificVariable.

Then you can do:

```
[ MyProcessSpecificVar value: foo. ] fork.

[ MyProcessSpecificVar value. ] fork.
```

etc, i.e. in same way as old implementation allows to do it.

But with new implementation , you can also use instances of it, so you don't have to create a new class per each process-specific var you might want to use:

```
mykey := MyProcessSpecificVar new.


[ mykey value ] fork.
[ mykey value: 10 ] fork.
```

Comment: In which case would I need the latter variant? What happens if I refer to `mykey` from two different processes?

Comment: In case of mykey, each process will have it's own value, just like in the case of different classes. This form can be used so that you do not need to define a new class for each PSV, but use the same class for similar (in nature) PSVs. For sample of PSV class look at the: TestLocalVariable

Comment: see `ProcessSpecificTest` for more details, and I don't think the first version makes sense anymore, unless you really want to have a very static global object per thread.